# Spring-Core JNDI Configuration with beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Lets take I have a class as shown below :

```
public interface UserDAO {
    public List<User> list();
}

public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public UserDAOImpl(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
 }
```

Let's assume JNDI configuration is done correctly in tomcat.

Now for spring bean mapping in many sites I found the below configuration:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/UsersDB"/>
</bean>

    <bean id="userDao" class="net.codejava.spring.dao.UserDAOImpl">
    <constructor-arg>
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Here is what my question , UserDAOImpl class is looking for DataSource object but we are injecting JndiObjectFactoryBean object[Which is not a subclass of DataSource] , since we are not even mentioning the factory method how or where the conversion is happening ?

Answer (score 1):

`JndiObjectFactoryBean` is bean of type `org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean`. This beans are used as a factory for an object to expose. Below are excerpts from the javadoc for `FactoryBean`;

> Interface to be implemented by objects used within a BeanFactory which are themselves factories for individual objects. If a bean implements this interface, it is used as a factory for an object to expose, not directly as a bean instance that will be exposed itself.
>
> NB: A bean that implements this interface cannot be used as a normal bean. **A FactoryBean is defined in a bean style, but the object exposed for bean references (getObject()) is always the object that it creates**.
>
> FactoryBeans can support singletons and prototypes, and can either create objects lazily on demand or eagerly on startup. The SmartFactoryBean interface allows for exposing more fine-grained behavioral metadata.

So when spring framework is autowiring the datasource to useDaoImpl it checks whether dataSource is a bean of type `FactoryBean` which it is in this case so it will assign the object from `getObject()` method of `JndiObjectFactoryBean` to the dataSource. If you want to understand this more take a look at `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.finishBeanfactoryInitialization(..)` and `DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons()` methods which perform the autowiring in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it is done but Spring Frameworks knows that beans is a Factory of `DataSource` beans, then it can inject the discovered datasource in your others beans.

I you want to know how it is done then you can look at the source code in [Spring Framework Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework)